# Postfix forward mails to external domains as (inline) bounce

Tags: postfix, spam, alias, mail-forwarding

My problem: I own a postfix server with several Aliases on it. For example:

info@my.tld => abc@gmail.com

If I now send a email from def@gmail.com to info@my.tld it get's forwarded to abc@gmail.com

But then Google sees the information: From: def@gmail.com To abc@gmail.com , checks SPF and co and concludes: There is a mail coming from external with an internal address => must be SPAM.

SO: Is it possible to make postfix forward such mails as inline bounce or to use local a local From: ?

Comment: What you are looking for is called SRS rewriting. I'll try and find the doc for it and add a proper answer

Comment: I found https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd and https://github.com/zoni/postforward

Thank you for the google search words - if your experience with this is positive I'll give it a try.